# Show SoapUrl in Message Microsof Dynamic Nav?

Tags: dynamic-programming, navision

i have a codeunite i want when i run the codeunite  the SoapUrl of my pages which i published as a web service  show in a message;

my published objects Object id = 50000 and 50001 i just want to display SoapUrl in message.

below is the code i tried .

Var
   WebService : Record Tenant Web Service;

```
 Run()
 WebService.FindSet;
 IF WebService."Object ID" = 50000 THEN
 BEGIN
  MESSAGE('name %1', WebService.SoapUrl");
 END;
```

But this code not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [GETURL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/geturl-function) function with `SOAP` as ClientType parameter.